# How to fix Cannot read property 'rowIndexes' of undefined in free-jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If inline edit is started by clicking in inline edit or toolbar inline edit button, javascript exception

```
Column 15TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowIndexes' of undefined
```

at http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:5135:15
 at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:384:23)    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:136:17)
  at jgrid.extend.getGridRowById (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:5133:9)
  at http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:5498:31
 at Function.jQuery.extend.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:384:23)    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js:136:17) 
   at jgrid.extend.setRowData (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:5495:9)
 at $.fn.jqGrid (http://localhost:52216/admin/Scripts/jqgrid-4.9.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js:2003:14)

occurs.

Exception occurs in getGridRowById at line

```
if (this.p.rowIndexes != null)
```

Code assumes that this is jqgrid, but in this case this is main windowsince it is called from line 2003 in jquery.jqgrid.src.js

```
return fn.apply(this, $.makeArray(arguments).slice(1));
```

This occurs in free jqgrid  from github with date 2015-07-24.
It does not occur in previous versions.
How to fix it ?

[image: exception]

Results from VS immediate window:

```
this
{...}
    [Methods]: {...}
    $grid: {...}
    animationStartTime: 8871.519383290184
    applicationCache: {...}
    autoedit: true
    BASE_URL: "/admin/"
    clientInformation: {...}
    clipboardData: {...}
    closed: false
    console: {...}
    data-mce-expando: 1
    DateTemplate: {...}
    defaultStatus: ""
    devicePixelRatio: 1.0499999523162841
    document: {...}
    doNotTrack: null
    editParams: {...}
    event: {...}
    external: {...}
    firstLoad: false
    formDeletingTemplate: {...}
    frameElement: null
    frames: {...}
    history: {...}
    idsOfSelectedRows: [ANDOMAKS,7]
    indexedDB: {...}
    innerHeight: 728
    innerWidth: 1090
    isColState: true
    isVisible: false
    jQuery11120852751018810201: {...}
    lastSelectedRow: "7"
    length: 0
    localStorage: {...}
    location: {http://localhost:52216/admin/Grid/Index/Klient?_user=admin&_company=1}
    maxConnectionsPerServer: 6
    Message: {...}
    msAnimationStartTime: 8871.519383290184
    msCrypto: {...}
    msIndexedDB: {...}
    myColumnsState: {...}
    myColumnStateName: "Klient.0.colState"
    name: ""
    navigator: {...}
    offscreenBuffering: "auto"
    onabort: null
    onafterprint: null
    onbeforeprint: null
    onbeforeunload: null
    onblur: null
    oncanplay: null
    oncanplaythrough: null
    onchange: null
    onclick: null
    oncontextmenu: null
    ondblclick: null
    ondrag: null
    ondragend: null
    ondragenter: null
    ondragleave: null
    ondragover: null
    ondragstart: null
    ondrop: null
    ondurationchange: null
    onemptied: null
    onended: null
    onfocus: null
    onfocusin: null
    onfocusout: null
    onhashchange: null
    onhelp: null
    oninput: null
    onkeydown: null
    onkeypress: null
    onkeyup: null
    onloadeddata: null
    onloadedmetadata: null
    onloadstart: null
    onmessage: null
    onmousedown: null
    onmouseenter: null
    onmouseleave: null
    onmousemove: null
    onmouseout: null
    onmouseover: null
    onmouseup: null
    onmousewheel: null
    onmsgesturechange: null
    onmsgesturedoubletap: null
    onmsgestureend: null
    onmsgesturehold: null
    onmsgesturestart: null
    onmsgesturetap: null
    onmsinertiastart: null
    onmspointercancel: null
    onmspointerdown: null
    onmspointerenter: null
    onmspointerleave: null
    onmspointermove: null
    onmspointerout: null
    < More... (The first 100 of 158 items were displayed.) >
this.each
undefined
```

Comment: It looks like this must be jqgrid. getGridRowByIt requires jqgrid rows. Your fix hides the error, function does not return proper result. Real fix should allow to return jqgrid row.

Comment: VS debugger shows like `this` is global window object, not jqgrid. This function requires jqgrid. So fix should allow to pass jqgrid to this function.

Comment: are you running this in setInterval or setTimeout? please show the enclosing function of the above line

Comment: I added results from immediate window to question. It looks like inside `this.each` function this is changed to window object. `this.each` returns undefined inside `each` method

Comment: I dont see any setInterval or setTimeout call in stack trace. Line which causes error is at https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js#L5137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but one sees in the call stack that the problem take place in `setRowData` called inside of you callback function `afterSaveFuncAfterAdd` which called inside of another callback function `aftersavefunc`. I suppose that you make some wrong call in the stack.

I recommend you to verify that `aftersavefunc` (called by `fullBoolCallback`) have correctly initialized `this` to the DOM of the grid. You have to use `.call` or `.apply` to call any child function (for example `afterSaveFuncAfterAdd.call(this, otherParameters);`). I suppose that some from the calls was without forwarding `this`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. I did'nt know that jqgrid objects  needs to passed as this to setRowData. This is not documented. It probably worked in ealier versions of jqgrid without passing this or maybe it starts to occurs if application code was refactored